# Rails: mailto in controller does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailto

I have the following code in my controller's create action:

```
if @record.save && @type == "email"
  redirect_to 'mailto:info@example.com?body=some text&subject=some subject'

elsif @record.save && @type == "sms"
  redirect_to 'sms:?&body=some text '

else
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

It works. However, I want the email address to be blank instead of "info@example.com".

I tried the usual way:

```
redirect_to 'mailto:?body=...'
```

And I tried to trick it:

```
redirect_to 'mailto:%20?body=...'
```

None of these work as the email app does not open - nothing happens at all. It only opens if there is an @ after mailto, which then prepopulates the address field - but I want it to be blank.

Is there a way to do it? I'm trying now for hours...

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes I tried it. But it does not work. The email app opens only when there is an address (at least a @).

Comment: Maybe it is depending on the particular e-mail app? I tried a '<a href="mailto:?body=some text&subject=some subject">Link</a>' from a fiddle and it works perfectly with Outlook.

Comment: It works for me too when I use the <a> tag in a view. I only have a problem when the code is in the controller. If I put it there without an email address it does not open anything - not on my Mac, not on my Windows machine, not on my iPhone, and not on my Android...

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and it work for me.

```
redirect_to 'mailto:?body=some&subject=some'
```

Also there is some error in your code. You saved `@record` twice.
Correct way:

```
if @type == "email" && @record.save
  redirect_to 'mailto:info@example.com?body=some_text&subject=some_subject'
elsif @type == "sms" && @record.save
  redirect_to 'sms:?&body=some text '
else
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: redirect_to 'mailto:?body=some&subject=some' does not open the email app. It opens only with an @ in the address...

Comment: I think your way is an improvement over the OP but I'd rather do separate conditionals for `@type` and saving the record. More explicit.